# T-SQL multiple select statements performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-performance

I need to execute about 20 select statements to get information for my app. I'm grouping the result sets into one, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to solve this (a more performatic way).

I'm following this approach:

```
SELECT TB_A.QTD,
TB_B.QTD
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS QTD
    FROM TB_A WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE TP = 2
    AND A = 1
    AND N = @N
) TB_A,
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) QTD
    FROM TB_B WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE G = @G
    AND U = @U
) TB_B,
...other 18 statements
```

PS: some variables like @n, @g and @u are parameters informed by user.

Comment: Just a warning, NOLOCK can cause you all sorts of strange problems like reading the same row twice or skipping some data completely.

Comment: A bit off topic but here is an article that discusses NOLOCK. All too often people use it "because it make my queries faster". I have never seen any viable proof that they are faster, but I have seen lots of proof that they produce quite strange results. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I also recommend to remove the `NOLOCK`. If you want more speed, then you need to create proper indexes. This can dramatically boost up speed of your query. Besindes that, there is normally no need to "help" the optimizer.

Comment: Just optimize the selects one at a time and nolock is not necessarily evil.  I use nolock all the time.  Clearly indexes on the where will help.

Answer (score 4):

Your queries are fine (I would use an explicit `CROSS JOIN` rather than `,`, because I abhor commas in the `FROM` clause).

For performance, two indexes would help:  `tb_a(TP, A, N)` and `tb_b(G, U)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got what I mean. I've edited the question to be more clear. Basically, I want to avoid 20 connections / selects

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio If you have 20 tables, you cannot avoid to have 20 selects.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio . . . Your solution would appear to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that a single huge query is typically bad for performance and that breaking it down into more manageable parts can help. Adding any covering or filtered indexes on what you're filtering by on the individual tables should help as well.

```
Declare @AQTD int,@BQTD int

Select @AQTD=COUNT(1)
FROM TB_A WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE TP = 2
AND A = 1
AND N = @N

Select @BQTD=COUNT(1) 
FROM TB_B WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE G = @G
AND U = @U

SELECT @AQTD,@BQTD
```

Comment: *"I've found that a single huge query is typically bad for performance"* ==> Only if you do it wrong.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio If your query is slow, then due to to missing indexes on your tables.

Answer (score 1):

I second @GordonLinoff. 
Alternatively, you can write it like this - but performance will be the same.

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM TB_A WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE TP = 2
    AND A = 1
    AND N = @N
) QTD_A, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) QTD
    FROM TB_B WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE G = @G
    AND U = @U
) QTD_B,
...other 18 statements
```

...Note, there is **no `FROM`** !

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the execution time, if all the queries are independent as it seems, you could run them in parallel from your application but it would load much more the server.